# Adding new values to mysql table through html

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I am trying to add new elements to my database on mysql through my webpage.

This is what I've got so far

```
<form action="MyCurrentPage.php" method="post" >
<label for="playername"> Player </label>
<input type="text" name="addplayer" id="playername"/>
<input type= "submit" value="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

and this

```
<?php
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
     $addplayerv=$_POST['addplayer'];
     $mysqli->select_db("player", $player);

     $sql="INSERT INTO player (nameofplayer) VALUES ('".$addplayerv."')";
    $mysqli->query($sql, $mysqli);
    $mysqli->close($mysqli);
     }


?>
```

I am getting the following errors:

- Notice: Undefined variable: player
- Warning: mysqli::select_db() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given
- Warning: mysqli::query() expects parameter 2 to be integer, object
  given
- Warning: mysqli::close() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given

Comment: error messages are clear... check the manual to see what are the expected parameter... where did you find `select_db` needs a second parameter ?

Comment: Where do you connect to database? see the documentation to every method http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.query.php

Comment: Read a guide or php manual.. 1º connect to db - 2º select db  - 3º execute queries. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php read first example!

Comment: Additionally you should be using parameterized queries. This is open to SQL injections.

Answer (score 0):

You have not declared `$player` you should do that first.
The `select_db()` function is unnesisary if you use `$mysli` like this: 
`$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");`

your query should execute after you did take these steps with this line:
`mysqli_query($mysqli,"INSERT INTO player (nameofplayer) VALUES ('".$addplayerv."')");`

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the Errors; 
 1. It doesn't seem like you have a Database Connection.
 2. Prefer PDO to mysqli_

I would do it this way instead:

```
<?php
//DATABASE CONNECTION CONFIGURATION:
defined("HOST")     or define("HOST",   "localhost");           //REPLACE WITH YOUR DB-HOST
defined("DBASE")    or define("DBASE",  "my_database");         //REPLACE WITH YOUR DB NAME
defined("USER")     or define("USER",   "root");                //REPLACE WITH YOUR DB-USER
defined("PASS")     or define("PASS",   "root");                //REPLACE WITH YOUR DB-PASS


if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $playerName     = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['addplayer']));  //PROTECT AGAINST ATTACKS

    try {
        $dbh        = new PDO('mysql:host='.HOST.';dbname='. DBASE,USER,PASS);
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $stmt       = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO player (nameofplayer) VALUES (:name)");
        $stmt->bindParam(':name', $playerName);
        $stmt->execute();

        //GARBAGE COLLECTION 
        $dbh        = null;
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }


}
```

I hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $addplayerv=$_POST['addplayer'];
        $mysqli->select_db("player");

        $sql="INSERT INTO player (nameofplayer) VALUES ('".$addplayerv."')";
        $mysqli->query($sql);
        $mysqli->close();
    }
?>
```

select_db() needs one parameter: the name of the database you're using.
query() only needs the sql query.
close() doesn't expect any parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :-

```
$con=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();}
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
$addplayerv=$_POST['addplayer'];
mysqli_select_db($con,"player");
$sql="INSERT INTO player (nameofplayer) VALUES ('".$addplayerv."')";
mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

}
mysqli_close($con);

This will work 100%.